# pdfMake - cannot open file

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfmake

I used this module on Nodejs : https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Here is my code to create it :

```
    const fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: './fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: './fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: './fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: './fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'
    }
};

let PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
let printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
let fs = require('fs');


module.exports.generateFile = function (data,callback) {

    let fileName = "Logins_" + data[0]["userLogin"] + ".pdf";
    let filePath = __dirname + "/files/" + fileName;

    let logins = [ ['userLogin', 'softwarePassword', 'softwareName'] ];
    for (let obj of data) {
        let arr = [];
        for(let x in obj){
            arr.push(obj[x]);
        }
        logins.push(arr);
    }

    let docDefinition = {
        content: [
            {
                table: {
                    // headers are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
                    // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
                    headerRows: 1,
                    widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

                    body: logins
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    try {

        let chunks = [];
        let result;

        let doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
        doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
        doc.end();
        callback(null,fileName,filePath)
    } catch (err){
        callback(err);
    }
    };
```

I got this screen :

Any ideas guys ?
In the callback, I use res.download with the filename and the filepath.
I tried everything

[image]

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658535/building-table-dynamically-with-pdfmake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building table dynamically with PDFMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658535/building-table-dynamically-with-pdfmake)

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: One of these two links answers had helped to find out the solution but I don't remember know which one it was ^^

Comment: Both are point to the same link.. Thanks i fixed my issue already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working solution tested on local and node server**

Why `pdfmake` cannot open file is because the file stream `fs` is still writing to the memory block, which makes it unreadable and the downloaded PDF would be corrupted with size of 0KB.

Solution: Add an event listener to the `fs.createWriteSteam` and wait for `fs` to finish writing then send file.

```js
var temp123;
pdfDoc.pipe(temp123 = fs.createWriteStream('./PDF/' + name), { encoding:'utf16' });

pdfDoc.end();

temp123.on('finish', async function () {
  // do send PDF file 
  res.download('name.pdf');
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and in my case `res` doesn't return a PDF back to the client.

Comment: @MikeB. Are you using express? The solution is for express, https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still having this issue.
Thanks to [Nikhil Nanjappa's article](https://kainikhil.medium.com/nodejs-how-to-generate-and-properly-serve-pdf-6835737d118e)
I've used this snippet on a NextJs project where I generated pdf on the server-side. Works like a charm!

```
const pdfMakePrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
const fs = require('fs');

function generatePdf(docDefinition, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
  try {
    const fontDescriptors = { ... };
    const printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fontDescriptors);
    const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

    doc.pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream('docs/filename.pdf').on("error", (err) => {
        errorCallback(err.message);
      })
    );

    doc.on('end', () => {
      successCallback("PDF successfully created and stored");
    });
    
    doc.end();
    
  } catch(err) {
    throw(err);
  }
};
```