# Nodejs PDFMake download unable to open

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfmake

I am now doing Nodejs, trying generate a PDF using PDFMake. After it's was generate, I want it to be downloaded immediately. However, after downloading the files, I couldn't open the file. It says "Failed to load PDF document."
The code I written are below.

```
var docDefinition = { content: 'test', };

var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('name.pdf'));

pdfDoc.end();

res.download('name.pdf');
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out my solution to this problem [pdfMake - cannot open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117885/pdfmake-cannot-open-file/49260310#49260310).

Why `pdfmake` cannot open file is because the file stream `fs` is still writing to the memory block, which makes it unreadable and the downloaded PDF would be corrupted with size of 0KB.

Solution: Add an event listener to the `fs.createWriteSteam` and wait for `fs` to finish writing then send file.

```js
var temp123;
pdfDoc.pipe(temp123 = fs.createWriteStream('./PDF/' + name), { encoding:'utf16' });

pdfDoc.end();

temp123.on('finish', async function () {
  // do send PDF file 
  res.download('name.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcis you saved my lots of time , deserve upvote .

Comment: in my case is 70 kb something but still Failed to load the PDF document error is showing. I am doing this
 ```const pdfDoc = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    return pdfDoc.getBase64((data)=>{
      return data;
    }); ```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the response object you can use the response object as a parameter of pdfDoc.pipe(response)

```js
pdfDoc.pipe(response);
```