# Angular PDFMake Dynamic Table with Nested JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, pdfmake

I have used a code I found on here [Building table dynamically with PDFMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658535/building-table-dynamically-with-pdfmake) it works perfectly fine with dynamic data coming from an API. But my problem is Nested JSON.

This is how the JSON looks like:

```
dataseries":[
      {
         "timepoint":3,
         "cloudcover":2,
         "seeing":6,
         "transparency":2,
         "lifted_index":10,
         "rh2m":2,
         "wind10m":{
            "direction":"N",
            "speed":2
         },
         "temp2m":23,
         "prec_type":"none"
      },
      {
         "timepoint":6,
         "cloudcover":2,
         "seeing":6,
         "transparency":2,
         "lifted_index":15,
         "rh2m":3,
         "wind10m":{
            "direction":"N",
            "speed":2
         },
         "temp2m":21,
         "prec_type":"none"
      },
```

I am trying to generate the content of **wind10m** specifically the *direction* and *speed* on the PDF file. How do I access and generate two different columns of *direction* and *speed*?

This is my stackblitz demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojgxtj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I saw your comments, and I updated my answer. If this solve your question, please upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [JSON.stringify](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrhmhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) instead of .toString()

> JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string,

optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

From:

```
dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
```

to

```
dataRow.push(JSON.stringify(row[column]));
```

**Update for nested wind10m column:**

You need to add the colSpan and rowSpan properties to the table rows.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrhmhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
  buildTableBody(data, columns, c2) {
    var body = [];

    //push first and second row
    body.push(columns);
    body.push(c2);
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      var dataRow = [];
      columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.text == 'timepoint' || column.text == 'cloudcover') {
          dataRow.push(JSON.stringify(row[column.text]));
        } else if (column.text == 'wind10m') {
          dataRow.push(row['wind10m']['direction']);
        } else {
          dataRow.push(row['wind10m']['speed']);
        }
      });
      body.push(dataRow);
    });

    return body;
  }

  generatePdf() {
    console.log('generatePdf');

    let docDefinition = {
      content: [
        { text: 'PDF Generate', style: 'header' },
        this.table(
          this.holder,
          //first row
          [
            { text: 'timepoint', rowSpan: 2 },
            { text: 'cloudcover', rowSpan: 2 },
            { text: 'wind10m', colSpan: 2 },
            '',
          ],
          //second row
          [
            '',
            '',
            { text: 'direction' },
            { text: 'Speed' },
          ]
        ),
      ],
    };
    pdfmake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
  }
```